# Searching the history of an item with temptable

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I was given a task to check how an item has changed and into what subproducts.
My logic was : i will use a function to check into what subproducts , my resource has turned into and rerun the function until there isn't a subproduct created. I want to have a temp table for every subproduct i have searched (thus not getting into a loop of some sort) and another temp table where i insert each product searched from my function. The function will repeat itself using the first product and after inserting the generated products will delete the top one (the one used by my function,thus having an end point when the table empties). I am stucked as i can not find a working way to make this work. Here is a snipet of my code.

I tried inserting into where not exists , but could not get it right.

```
declare @item NVARCHAR(250)
declare @return NVARCHAR(250)
declare @resultstable TABLE ( [order] NVARCHAR(50),[return] NVARCHAR(50),[genItem] NVARCHAR(50),[BatchNo] NVARCHAR(50),[IsItem] NVARCHAR(50))
declare @tempSearch TABLE ( [Exists] NVARCHAR(50))

SET @item = -- my searching item


INSERT INTO @resultstable
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[fuction] (@item)
INSERT INTO  @tempSearch
SELECT TOP (1) [BatchNo] FROM @RESULTSTABLE
```

---

```
WHILE( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @resultstable)>0)
  BEGIN
    SET @return = (SELECT TOP(1) [return] FROM @resultstable)
----here is my problem in the if statement
    IF(@return=(SELECT [Exists] FROM @resultstable WHERE [EXISTS] = @return ))

     BEGIN 

      INSERT INTO @tempSearch
      SELECT TOP (1) [return] FROM @resultstable

      INSERT INTO @resultstable
      SELECT *
      FROM [dbo].[function] (@return)

     DELETE TOP(1) FROM @resultstable

    END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
       DELETE TOP (1) FROM @resultstable        
     END 
END
```

The expected output should be 0 in the first Temp table @resultstable because of the delete top statement. For the second Table @tempSearch i should be having any item that has been searched in the order that was given. Mostly every item used by the function produces 3-6 subproducts. Keep in mind that the procedure stops when my function produces 0 results(could not find any generated product). Any help will be mostly appreciated as i haven not got a lot of experience in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using MySql? That syntax seems more sql-server. If is sqlserver. 
Please remove the mysql tag and add the sql-server tag. Then, regarding your problem, I think that you must change your IF condition to this:

```
IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 [EXISTS] FROM @tempSearch WHERE [EXISTS] = @return ))
```

If the new return item does not exist on your tempsearch table then go ahead and do what you need.

Also not sure why you are doing this:

```
INSERT INTO  @tempSearch
SELECT TOP (1) [BatchNo] FROM @RESULTSTABLE
```

Comment: Regarding your first questions this is mssql.,
Regarding the last snipet , i am putting in the ( if i have searched this again ) item that i have just used for my first function . Just in case it ever comes up .

Comment: It seems this worked like a charm ! Will update later on after my checks . None the less thank you :)